# How do I send a variable from back end and display it on the console in the front end?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a NodeJS variable and I want to send to AngularJS side without storing it into the database. The variable has JSON data and I want to print it on the Angular console. How do I do it?

Comment: Any relevant front end code to show?

Answer (score 0):

If you call your backend route `/all` with any ajax calls on front-end it'll give you value of `parsed` on front-end to use. Your front-end code can be something like

```
fetch("/all")
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(val => {
   // This console log displays in browser console on front-end.
   console.log(val);
 })
```

`fetch` api is only one way. Based on your front-end libraries, you can use jQuery's `$.get` or any other libraries like `axios`.